# Oracle Apex 5.0.1 IRR No data found with query that returns data on SQL workshop

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I use a select query in interactive report that has subqueries in it. It gives me result in the SQL workshop of APEX but gives me "No Data Found" in the interactive report. Any solution/fix?

Comment: In SQL workshop, try to run your query under schema that is same as the one used in application's "parse as schema" setting. you will find this setting under application property. more info on parsing schema here --> http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E59726_01/doc.50/e39147/bldr_attr.htm#CHDDBHCD

Comment: Does your query use any parameter? Usually this is a parameter issue.

Comment: There was a bug in my query where. My input parameters were of incorrect name. Thanks anayways